# IE 8 does'nt load html properly

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in this website that's really getting no my nerves. The website renders well on Chrome and Firefox, the problem is on IE (surprise!). When I load it locally it renders fine, disploaying all elements as it should. But when I load it on the servert, it just ignores the CSS rules. And when I hit f12 to inspect element, it doesn't show the opening tags of any elements, just the closing ones, which is really strange. I've uploaded all the files correctly, checked the conditional comments, went through the lines after any typo and found nothing. really hope you could help me with this. Here is the website:

```
palcco.com.br/ftp/kunzler
```

I really hope you can help me with this. It's very likely a rookie mistake or something that escaped from my sight.

Thanks in advance.

```
The code:




<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Index</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="facebox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!--[if (IE)]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css">
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if !(IE)]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- Media Query 1 -->
<link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-   width:1600px) and (max-width:1920px)" />
<!-- Media Query 2 -->
<link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-         
width:1920px)" />
<!--<![endif]-->

<script type=
"text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">      

</script>
<!--<script src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
<script src="js/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/valida.js"></script>
<!--<script src="PIE/PIE.js"></script>-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $j(".banner").easySlider({
            auto: true,
            continuous: true,
            nextId: "slider1next",
            prevId: "slider1prev"
        });
    }); 
</script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<section id="home">

 <header id="topo">

 <section class="logo">
  <section class="container">
    <a href="#">
     <h2>Kunzler</h2>
     <img src="img/logo_relevo.fw.png" alt="Kunzler">
    </a>
    </section><!--container-->

    <h1>Para tudo que combina com você</h1>

   </section><!--logo-->



   <nav id="menu">
   <section class="container">
    <ul>
     <li class="menu_princ"><a href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
       <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="empresa.html" class="empresa" rel="facebox">Empresa</a></li>
       <li><a href="#produtos" class="smoothScroll">Produtos</a></li>
       <li><a href="#receitas" class="smoothScroll">Receitas</a></li>
       <li><a href="#filmes" class="smoothScroll">Filmes</a></li>
       <li><a href="#contato" class="smoothScroll">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </section><!--container-->
   </nav>   

 </header>

 <section class="container_banner">
 <section class="banner">
  <ul>              
<li><a href="#"><img src="img/banner1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="img/banner2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="img/banner_tropical.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/banner_brasileirinho.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/banner_defumado.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>       
  </ul>
 </section>
 </section>    

  </section><!--home-->

<section id="produtos">

 <section class="fundo">

 <section class="return">
   <a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">
    <img src="img/arrowHome2.png"/>
   </a>
  </section>

  <h2>Produtos</h2>

  <div id="arrTrabalhos">

  <section class="container">

   <div class="arrGeral">

    <div class="arrItens">

     <div class="arrItem">     
      <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
       <section class="embalagem">   
       <section class="aba_embalagem">
       <h3>Tradicional Pote</h3>
       </section>
       <a href="produto1.html" rel="facebox">
        <img src="img2/tradPote.fw.png" alt="Tradicional Pote">
       </a>  
  </section>
      </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

      <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
       <section class="embalagem_inf">
       <a href="produto2.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="img2/tropicalSache.fw.png" alt="Tropical Sachê">
       </a>
       <section class="aba_embalagem_inf">
       <h3>Tropical Sachê</h3>
      </section>
      </section>
     </div><!--blocoMostra BlocoBottom-->
     </div><!--arrItem-->

     <div class="arrItem">
      <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
       <section class="embalagem">
       <section class="aba_embalagem">
       <h3>Tradicional Sachê</h3>
       </section>
       <a href="produto3.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="img2/tradSache.fw.png" alt="Tradicional Sachê">
       </a>
       </section>
      </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

      <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
        <section class="embalagem_inf">
        <a href="produto4.html" rel="facebox">
        <img src="img2/tropicalPote.fw.png" alt="Tropical Pote">
        </a>
        <section class="aba_embalagem_inf">
        <h3>Tropical Pote</h3>
      </section>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->
   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">
    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="embalagem">
      <section class="aba_embalagem">
      <h3>Light Sachê</h3>
      </section>
      <a href="produto5.html" rel="facebox">   
      <img src="img2/lightSache.fw.png" alt="Light Sachê">
      </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="embalagem_inf">
     <a href="produto6.html" rel="facebox">
     <img src="img2/brasileirinho_emb.fw.png" alt="Brasileirinho">
     </a>
     <section class="aba_embalagem_inf">
     <h3>Brasileirinho</h3>
     </section>
    </section> 
   </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->
   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">
    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="embalagem">
     <section class="aba_embalagem">
     <h3>Light Pote</h3>
     </section>
     <a href="produto7.html" rel="facebox">
     <img src="img2/lightPote.fw.png" alt="Light Pote">
     </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="embalagem_inf">
     <a href="produto8.html" rel="facebox">
     <img src="img2/defumado_emb.fw.png" alt="Defumado">
     </a>
     <section class="aba_embalagem_inf">
     <h3>Defumado</h3>
     </section>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->
   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">
    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="embalagem">
     <section class="aba_embalagem">
     <h3>Orégano</h3>
     </section>
     <a href="produto9.html" rel="facebox">
     <img src="img2/oreganoEmb.fw.png" alt="Orégano">
     </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="embalagem_inf">
     <a href="produto10.html" rel="facebox">
     <img src="img2/massaCaseira_emb.fw.png" alt="Massa Caseira">
     </a>
     <section class="aba_embalagem_inf">
     <h3>Massa Caseira</h3>
     </section>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->
   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">
    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="embalagem">
     <section class="aba_embalagem">
     <h3>Batata Palha</h3>
     </section>
     <a href="produto11.html" rel="facebox">
     <img src="img2/batataPalha_emb.fw.png" alt="Batata Palha">
     </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->
   </div><!--arrItem-->

    </div><!--arrItens-->

    <div class="arrAncora">
     <div class="arrBox">
      <div class="arrBg">
       <div class="arrBt"></div>
      </div><!--arrBg-->
     </div><!--arrBox-->
    </div><!--arrAncora-->

   </div><!--arrGeral-->

   </section><!--container-->

  </div><!--arrTrabalhos-->

  </section><!--fundo-->

  </section><!--#produtos-->

     <section id="receitas">

 <section class="return">
   <a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">
    <img src="img/arrowHome.fw.png" />
   </a>
  </section>

   <h2>Receitas</h2>

   <div id="arrTrabalhos">

    <section class="container">

     <div class="arrGeral">

      <div class="arrItens">

       <div class="arrItem">

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="box_receitas">
      <section class="aba_receitas">
       <h3>Batata Assada</h3>
      </section>
      <a href="receita1.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="img/imgbatata.jpg" alt="Batata Assada">
      </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="box_receitas_inf">
      <a href="receita2.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgreceitas/receita_tomatesecos.jpg" alt="Tomates Secos">
      </a>
      <section class="aba_receitas_inf">
       <h3>Tomates secos</h3>
      </section>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="box_receitas">
      <section class="aba_receitas">
       <h3>Couve-flor</h3>
      </section>
      <a href="receita3.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgreceitas/receita_couveflor.jpg" alt="Couve Flor">
      </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="box_receitas_inf">
      <a href="receita4.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgreceitas/receita_brigadeiro.jpg" alt="Brigadeiro de Queijo">
      </a>
     <section class="aba_receitas_inf">
      <h3>Brigadeiro de queijo</h3>
     </section>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra BlocoBottom-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="box_receitas">
      <section class="aba_receitas">
       <h3>Panqueca de frango</h3>
      </section>
      <a href="receita5.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgreceitas/receita_panqueca.jpg" alt="Panqueca de Frango">
      </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="box_receitas_inf">
      <a href="receita6.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgreceitas/receita_pudim.jpg" alt="Pudim de Leite">
      </a>
     <section class="aba_receitas_inf">
      <h3>Pudim de leite</h3>
     </section>
    </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="box_receitas">
      <section class="aba_receitas">
       <h3>Quiche de queijo</h3>
      </section>
       <a href="receita7.html" rel="facebox">
        <img src="imgreceitas/receita_quiche.jpg" alt="Quiche de Queijo">
       </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra BlocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="box_receitas_inf">
      <a href="receita8.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgreceitas/receita_risoto_queijo.jpg" alt="Risoto de Queijo">
      </a>
     <section class="aba_receitas_inf">
      <h3>Risoto de queijo</h3>
     </section>
    </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="box_receitas">
      <section class="aba_receitas">
       <h3>Fondue de Queijo</h3>
      </section>
       <a href="receita9.html" rel="facebox">
        <img src="imgreceitas/receita_fondue.jpg" alt="Fondue de Queijo">
       </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra BlocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="box_receitas_inf">
      <a href="receita10.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgreceitas/receita_arroz.jpg" alt="Arroz ao Forno">
      </a>
     <section class="aba_receitas_inf">
      <h3>Arroz ao Forno</h3>
     </section>
    </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="box_receitas">
      <section class="aba_receitas">
       <h3>Atum Grelhado</h3>
      </section>
       <a href="receita11.html" rel="facebox">
        <img src="imgreceitas/receita_atum_grelhado.jpg" alt="Atum Grelhado">
       </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra BlocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="box_receitas_inf">
      <a href="receita12.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgreceitas/receita_capeletti.jpg" alt="Capeletti de Forno">
      </a>
     <section class="aba_receitas_inf">
      <h3>Capeletti de Forno</h3>
     </section>
    </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="box_receitas">
      <section class="aba_receitas">
       <h3>Empadão de Queijo</h3>
      </section>
       <a href="receita13.html" rel="facebox">
        <img src="imgreceitas/receita_empadao.jpg" alt="Empadão de Queijo">
       </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra BlocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="box_receitas_inf">
      <a href="receita14.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgreceitas/receita_frango_queijo.jpg" alt="Frango ao Queijo    

Parmesão">
      </a>
     <section class="aba_receitas_inf">
      <h3>Frango ao queijo</h3>
     </section>
    </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="box_receitas">
      <section class="aba_receitas">
       <h3>Nhoque de Queijo</h3>
      </section>
       <a href="receita15.html" rel="facebox">
        <img src="imgreceitas/receita_nhoque.jpg" alt="Nhoque de Queijo">
       </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra BlocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="box_receitas_inf">
      <a href="receita16.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgreceitas/receita_torta_doce.jpg" alt="Torta doce de Queijo">
      </a>
     <section class="aba_receitas_inf">
      <h3>Torta de Queijo</h3>
     </section>
    </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="box_receitas">
      <section class="aba_receitas">
       <h3>Pão de Queijo</h3>
      </section>
       <a href="receita17.html" rel="facebox">
        <img src="imgreceitas/receita_pao_queijo.jpg" alt="Pão de Queijo Parmesão">
       </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra BlocoTop-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

  </div><!--arrItens-->

  <div class="arrAncora">
   <div class="arrBox">
    <div class="arrBg">
     <div class="arrBt"></div>
    </div><!--arrBg-->
   </div><!--arrBox-->
  </div><!--arrAncora-->

     </div><!--arrGeral-->

    </section><!--container-->

   </div><!--arrTrabalhos-->

 </section><!--receitas-->

 <section id="filmes">

  <section class="fundo">

  <section class="return">
   <a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">
    <img src="img/arrowHome2.png"/>
   </a>
  </section>

  <h2>Filmes</h2>

   <div id="arrTrabalhos">

    <section class="container">

     <div class="arrGeral">

      <div class="arrItens">

       <div class="arrItem">

        <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
         <section class="box_filmes">
          <section class="aba_filmes">
           <h3>Kunzler Light</h3>
          </section>
          <a href="filme1.html" rel="facebox">
           <img src="imgVideo/video1.jpg" alt="Kunzler Light">
          </a>
         </section>
        </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

        <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
         <section class="box_filmes_inf">
          <a href="filme2.html" rel="facebox">
           <img src="imgVideo/video2.jpg" alt="Kunzler Orégano">
          </a>
         <section class="aba_filmes_inf">
          <h3>Kunzler Orégano</h3>
         </section>
    </section>
        </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

       </div><!--arrItem-->

       <div class="arrItem">

        <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
         <section class="box_filmes">
          <section class="aba_filmes">
           <h3>Tropical</h3>
          </section>
          <a href="filme3.html" rel="facebox">
           <img src="imgVideo/video3.jpg" alt="Tropical">
          </a>
         </section>
        </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

        <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
         <section class="box_filmes_inf">
          <a href="filme4.html" rel="facebox">
           <img src="imgVideo/video4.jpg" alt="Boas Festas">
          </a>
         <section class="aba_filmes_inf">
          <h3>Boas Festas</h3>
         </section>
        </section>
        </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

       </div><!--arrItem-->

       <div class="arrItem">

        <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
         <section class="box_filmes">
          <section class="aba_filmes">
           <h3>Canal Kunzler</h3>
          </section>
          <a href="filme5.html" rel="facebox">
           <img src="imgVideo/video5.jpg" alt="Canal Kunzler">
          </a>
         </section>
        </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

        <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
         <section class="box_filmes_inf">
          <a href="filme6.html" rel="facebox">
           <img src="imgVideo/video6.jpg" alt="Pipoca e Pão de Queijo">
          </a>
         <section class="aba_filmes_inf">
          <h3>Pipoca e Pão de Queijo</h3>
         </section>
        </section>
        </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="box_filmes">
      <section class="aba_filmes">
       <h3>Arroz de Forno</h3>
      </section>
      <a href="filme7.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgVideo/video7.jpg" alt="Arroz de Forno">
      </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="box_filmes_inf">
      <a href="filme8.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgVideo/video8.jpg" alt="Kunzler 50 Anos">
      </a>
     <section class="aba_filmes_inf">
      <h3>Kunzler 50 Anos</h3>
     </section>
    </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="box_filmes">
      <section class="aba_filmes">
       <h3>Cachorro-Quente Especial</h3>
      </section>
      <a href="filme9.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgVideo/video9.jpg" alt="Cachorro Quente Especial">
      </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="box_filmes_inf">
      <a href="filme10.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgVideo/video10.jpg" alt="Lasanha Tropical">
      </a>
     <section class="aba_filmes_inf">
      <h3>Lasanha Tropical</h3>
     </section>
    </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

   <div class="arrItem">

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoTop">
     <section class="box_filmes">
      <section class="aba_filmes">
       <h3>Pizza no Pão</h3>
      </section>
      <a href="filme11.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgVideo/video11.jpg" alt="Pizza no Pão">
      </a>
     </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoTop-->

    <div class="blocoMostra blocoBottom">
     <section class="box_filmes_inf">
      <a href="filme12.html" rel="facebox">
       <img src="imgVideo/video12.jpg" alt="Kunzler">
      </a>
     <section class="aba_filmes_inf">
      <h3>Kunzler</h3>
     </section>
    </section>
    </div><!--blocoMostra blocoBottom-->

   </div><!--arrItem-->

  </div><!--arrItens-->

  <div class="arrAncora">
   <div class="arrBox">
    <div class="arrBg">
     <div class="arrBt"></div>
    </div><!--arrBg-->
   </div><!--arrBox-->
  </div><!--arrAncora-->

     </div><!--arrGeral-->

    </section><!--container-->

   </div><!--arrTrabalhos-->

   </section><!--fundo-->

 </section><!--filmes-->

 <section id="contato">

 <section class="container">

 <section class="return">
   <a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">
    <img src="img/arrowHome.fw.png" />
   </a>
  </section>

  <h2>Contato</h2> 

  <section class="form">
   <section class="campos">
    <form onsubmit="return valida(this);" action="enviar_contato.php" method="post">

     <input type="text" name="nome" value="NOME"
      onclick="this.value='';" onblur="javascript:if (this.value=='')      

{this.value='NOME'};"/>
      <!--<p>&nbsp;</p>-->
      <input type="text" name="telefone" value="TELEFONE"
      onclick="this.value='';" onblur="javascript:if (this.value=='')     

{this.value='TELEFONE'};"/>
      <!--<p>&nbsp;</p>-->
      <input type="text" name="email" value="E-MAIL"
      onclick="this.value='';" onblur="javascript:if (this.value=='') {this.value='E-   

MAIL'};"/>
         <!--<p>&nbsp;</p>-->


   </section><!--campos-->

   <section class="mensagem">
     <textarea class="cxtxt"  name="mensagem" value="MENSAGEM"
      onclick="this.value='';" onblur="javascript:if (this.value=='')          

{this.value='MENSAGEM'};">MENSAGEM</textarea> 

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK" onclick="valida()"/></input> 
     </form>

   </section><!--mensagem-->

   <section id="novidades">
   <section class="container">
    <h4>novidades</h4>
    <form onsubmit="return valida(this);" action="enviar_novidades.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="novidades" value="E-MAIL"
          onclick="this.value='';" onblur="javascript:if (this.value=='') 

{this.value='E-MAIL'};"/>

     <input name="enviar" type="submit" value="OK" />

    </form>
    </section>
   </section>

  <section id="socialMedia">
   <section class="socialMediaIcon">
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/QueijoKunzler" target="_blank">
    <img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
   </a>

   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/tvkunzler" target="_blank">
    <img src="img/youtube.png" alt="Youtube">
   </a>

   <a href="https://twitter.com/queijokunzler" target="blank">
    <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
   </a>

   <a href="www.instagram/queijokunzler" target="blank">
    <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Instagram">
   </a>

   <h4><span>rede</span>
   <br>social</h4>

   </section><!--socialMediaIcon-->

  </section><!--socialMedia-->  

  </section><!--form-->

 </section><!--container-->

</section><!--contato-->

 <footer id="rodape">

 <section id="fundo_rodape">


  <nav id="menu_rodape">
  <section class="container">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#produtos" class="smoothScroll">Produtos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#receitas" class="smoothScroll">Receitas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#filmes" class="smoothScroll">Filmes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contato" class="smoothScroll">Contato</a></li>    
   </ul>
   </section>
  </nav>

  <section class="trabalho">
    <a href="trabalhe.html" class="trabalhe" rel="facebox"><p>Trabalhe Conosco</p></a>
   </section>


    <p>Todos os direitos reservados à KUNZLER<br>
     Fale Conosco: 51 3382.9000 |<br /> kunzler@kunzler.com.br</p>

   <section id="logo_rodape">
    <img src="img/logo_relevo_rodape.fw.png" alt="">
   </section>

   <section id="logo50">
    <img src="img/50anos.jpg" alt="">
   </section>

  </section><!--fundo_rodape-->

 </footer> 




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a doctype, your document appears to be missing one. See these articles: http://alistapart.com/article/doctype and http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype.

Chrome and Firefox are typically more forgiving of these types of errors – while IE8 and below are not.

Comment: Here is the doctype, I must have missed it:   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 0):

ie8 doesn't support html5 tags like `<section> or <nav>`

add this cdn in the head for ie8 to display html5 tags

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks, this cdn worked! Despite IE doesn't support the html5 tags, I could view them when loading the site locally. The problem was when it as live on the server. Thanks a lot for such a fast response, I really appreciate it!

Comment: By the way, I think a few people may agree with me if I sy IE didn't need to exist...

Comment: yup its my pleasure to help

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr.js can fix what ails ya. http://modernizr.com/